# C# Thread memory consumption

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

I have a process that kicks off 15 parallel threads using basic Thread.Start() where each thread is ApartmentStateSTA. The Visual Studio memory manager showed these threads were consuming an ever increasing memory amount so I took all the useful code out and am left with the following code segment. It does nothing but report each time memory consumption has grown by 100M. The process memory starts at 155M and quickly grows to 500M in 30 secs and continues to grow.

**What is consuming the memory or rather what trick do I need to stop such tremendous growth?** The GC.Collect statement made no difference nor did Sleep (in case I needed to give the GC some breathing room.). Also does not matter if I run this in the debugger or as release.exe.

```
long snapshotMemory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PagedMemorySize64;
long totalMemory = snapshotMemory;

while (true)
{
    totalMemory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PagedMemorySize64;
    if (totalMemory - snapshotMemory > 100000000) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Memory=" + (totalMemory/1000000).ToString()+"M");
        snapshotMemory = totalMemory;

        GC.Collect();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: And code starting threads is...?

Comment: I haven't tried to run this, but I have found that GetCurrentProcess() returns a disposable object. My guess is that you're allocating a gazillion of these objects in a short time, by looping, without disposing of them.

Comment: Code to start thread is in a for loop 1 to 15. 
Note that all references to any of these parms has been stripped from the while loop.

````Thread thread = new Thread(TaskCompareRows);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
ThreadParms parms = new ThreadParms(setKey, keyColumnsTrue1, keyColumnsClone1, startTime);
thread.Start(parms);
threads.Add(thread);````

Comment: How would I dispose of GetCurrentProcess()? I tried:  ````var memory = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); totalMemory = memory.PagedMemorySize64; memory = null; ```` but that made no difference.

Comment: `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` needs to be in a `using` block, you are leaking it every time. `GC.Collect()` doesn't help, you would have needed `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` (bad idea, but good debugging tool to see you are leaking). So you would do `using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()) { totalMemory = process.PagedMemorySize64; }`

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with [tag:visual-studio] or with [tag:multithreading]

Comment: You had a problem. You somehow came up with a solution  which involved 15 STA threads. I can **immediately** tell you that was the wrong solution. But if you want help solving your problem, please present it, rather than your botched solution. Please note: The problem will not contain the word thread at all, let alone STA.

Comment: And I'm guessing (but please don't use this to try to "fix" your current architecture) that the memory growth is because your STA threads aren't honoring the STA contract by running message pumps

Comment: The solution MUST contain STA as the loop involves accessing Sybase using OLEDB which simply will not run using MTA. Classifying my solution as 'botched' without knowing all the facts is premature. I purposely did not supply those facts cause I am not looking for help on high volume processing via ASEOLEDB.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface. The using clause eliminated the leak.

Comment: @Charlieface: if you don't mind: while the `using` advice is of course the correct one, why would `GC.Collect();` not work here? (not a rhetorical question)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Because `GC.Collect` does not wait for finalizers, nor does it collect anything in Gen1 or Gen2. So anything with a finalizer is going to get moved to Gen1, then wait for the finalizer thread to catch up (which it may never if there is a lot of objects) and wait for the next Gen1 collection. So it's just a waste of time doing Gen0 collections. Either way, you shouldn't rely on GC to do this, you should dispose properly

Comment: Hi @user610342 , glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering and accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)